# Setting fstype when using volumeClaimTemplates within statefulSets in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to set the fstype when using volumeClaimTemplates within kubernetes StatefulSets.

I'm using Azuredisk which defaults to ext4 but ideally I'd like to set xfs.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

(kubernetes 1.5.1)

Comment: Interested too. Just faced it. Looking through API spec it doesn't seem to be possible because claim could represent FS itself (think of NFS)

Comment: It is impossible as of v1.6.  However, there is a [PR](https://github.comr/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/40805) which makes it possible.